# R function to combine rows based on duplicates in specific columns and add value to a new column based on

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a very large data frame ('df') that has many duplicated rows that need consolidation. These duplicated rows represent different categories, and the values that correspond to these categories need to I need to move to a new column and be matched by ID and the first part of the category (e.g. A, B, C). Below is an illustration of what I'm looking for. I apologize for the lack of information, as I'm very new to RStudio.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

```r
df <- df%>%
  melt(id.vars = c("ID", "Category"))
```

Comment: Next time do not post images as data since it is not copy-pasteable for us to run the codes. You can either create your own data frame using `df <- data.frame(...)` or use `dput(df)`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a new column specifying what `Category` to join on (e.g. A, B or C) (assigned to `df2`). Then `left_join` a set of `df2` that does not contain `_2` in `Category` with a set that does (the two `filter` operations).

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df |> mutate(gp = sub("_.*", "", Category))

left_join(filter(df2, !grepl("_2", Category)), 
          filter(df2, grepl("_2", Category)) |> select(ID, gp, New_value = value), 
          by = c("ID", "gp")) |> 
  select(-gp)

  ID Category value New_value
1  1      A_1    43        12
2  2      B_1    46        10
3  3      C_1    99        NA
4  2      D_1    20        NA
```

#### Data

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:3, 2, 2, 1), 
                 Category = c("A_1", "B_1", "C_1", "B_2", "D_1", "A_2"), 
                 value = c(43, 46, 99, 10, 20, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

With {dplyr}

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:3, 2, 2, 1), 
  Category = c("A_1", "B_1", "C_1", "B_2", "D_1", "A_2"), 
  Value = c(43, 46, 99, 10, 20, 12)
)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(substr(Category, 1, 1), ID) %>% 
  summarize(Category = Category[[1]], New_Value = Value[2], Value = Value[1], .groups = "drop") %>% 
  select(ID, Category, Value, New_Value)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>      ID Category Value New_Value
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 A_1         43        12
#> 2     2 B_1         46        10
#> 3     3 C_1         99        NA
#> 4     2 D_1         20        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>